# Is it possible to access the module or view class from inside a request

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with a context processor to have the same object on every page.
It is working so far.

```py
# /core/context_processor.py
# (is correctly linked in settings.py)
def default(request):
    context = {'email': Email()}
    return context
```

Now i want to implement a "TAG" constant in every Django module.
I want to have it accessible in every view context without passing it from every View class

It should be similar to accessing the "{{request.path}}" inside the template but explicite.

```py
# /home/views.py
TAG = "TagOfHome"

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/list.html'
```

```py
# /addresses/views.py
TAG = "TagOfAddresses"

class AddressView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'address/list.html'
```

Now i want to access the TAG constant from the inside of every Template.

If it is a view of the addresses module it should be "TagOfAddresses", at home views it should be "TagOfHome" etc.

How can i achieve this?
Can i access the TAG somehow from within the context processor (request)?

---

**Edit:**

Thanks to @grrrrrr i could solved it using the 'request.resolver_match'.
But i didn't want to have 'config-stuff' inside of a module.
Therefore i created a dict in the settings.py:

```py
TAGS = {
        'core': 'home',
        'addressbook': 'address',
        'files': 'files'
    }
```

```py
# /core/context_processor.py
from config.settings import TAGS

def default(request):
    context = {'email': Email()}
    ...
    module = request.resolver_match.func.view_class.__module__.split('.')[0]
    context['tag'] = TAGS.get(module, 'default')
    return context
```

Comment: This smells like an XY Problem.

Comment: Create a mixin class that you add to all your views. Assuming all your views descend from `View` (which `TemplateView` does), you could override `dispatch()` method in your mixin to first add the `TAG` attribute to `request` and then call `super().dispatch()`. That way your request would have the `TAG` attribute in the context processor.

Comment: @Frank: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @dirkgroten: Am i right that i would avoid this xy-Problem, if i would only ask such like "How can I create a module related constant that is automatically transported to the cbv template-context of this module?"

Comment: No, it's about what you're trying to achieve with the tags in your (base) template. I'm not sure you're asking the wrong question, but what @dfundako is trying to say is that maybe there's a totally different route to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user [ResolverMatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch) to get the app name as well as other metadata about the request's resolved url.

For example in your template you could use
`{{ request.resolver_match.app_name }}` or customize the behavior in your context processor to return the `TAG`:

```
def default(request):
    context = {'email': Email()}
    if request.resolver_match.app_name == 'home':
        context['TAG'] = 'TagOfHome'
    elif ...
    return context
```